# TypeError : Property does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a type script for the react project. I have defined the type for all values, but prop.option?I can't get the value of the name. Please tell me the answer.

```
type PropTypes = {
  option?: OptionType[]
}

type OptionType = {
  id?: number
  name?: string
  price: number
  quantity: number
}

function OrderItemPCForm(props: PropTypes) {

  console.log('===>', props.option?.name)
return(<div>...</div>)}
```

```
Property 'name' does not exist on type 'OptionType[]'.
```

Comment: Option is an array of  OptionType
You would need to extract an element from it and then access the name property, for instance:  props.option.map( (individualOption) => console.log(individualOption.name) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem was you defined `option` as an array (not an object)

```
option?: OptionType[]
```

so that when you try to access values from

```
console.log('===>', props.option?.name)
```

It will throw an error because you try to get `name` from `option` object which is not defined

It has 2 ways to fix

The first one is you should remove an array definition on `option`

```
type PropTypes = {
  option?: OptionType //removed `[]`
}
```

The second fix can be

```
console.log('===>', props.option[index].name) //index can be populated from a loop
```

But it also depends on your intention which type you want to achieve (an array or an object on `option`)

Comment: @김유경, Nick is right. You just need to make `option` prop type just an object not an array of `OptionType`. And everything will work fine